# mysqli bind_param not working

Tags: mysqli

I have the following query which working fine.

```
$stmt = $sql->prepare("INSERT INTO _dashboard_users(
            Email,
            Password,
            FirstName,
            LastName,
            BusinessName,
            BusinessRole,
            Address,
            City,
            State,
            PostalCode,
            Phone,
            Website) VALUES(?,md5(?),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");            
        $stmt->bind_param("ssssssssssis",
            $Email,
            $Password,
            $FirstName,
            $LastName,
            $BusinessName,
            $BusinessRole,
            $Address,
            $City,
            $State,
            $PostalCode,
            $Phone,
            $Website);
        $stmt->execute();
```

But this one throwing a headache.

```
$stmt = $sql->prepare("INSERT INTO scrape(
            Kategorie,
            Hersteller,
            Artikelnummer,
            Bezeichnung,
            EAN,
            UPC,
            Beschreibung,
            Technische_Daten,
            Sprache,
            URL,
            Marktrelease,
            Bild) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
        $stmt->bind_param("ssssssssssss",
            $Kategorie,
            $Hersteller,
            $Artikelnummer,
            $Bezeichnung,
            $EAN,
            $UPC,
            $Beschreibung,
            $Technische_Daten,
            $Sprache,
            $URL,
            $Marktrelease,
            $Bild);
        $stmt->execute();
```

Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object~

Can anyone give me a reason why this is happening? I am 100% sure what I am writing, bind_param is a member function of $stmt.

```
**UPDATE:** I initiliazed $sql like this $sql = new mysqli(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASS,DB_NAME);
```

Answer (score 1):

You second query returns an error. The `$sql->prepare` fails, so `$stmt` is not an object (as told in your error). You can't call a method on a non-object.

Comment: Oh really? once i did the initialization $stmt = $sql->prepare() became an object. So, how did you find it $sql->prepare failed?

Comment: `Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object`. Your error told me.

Comment: can you take a look at the query i did? also, you can compare it to the first query which is working fine.

Comment: You may have an error in the fields. Just run it into phpmyadmin, or the mysql command line.

Comment: Ok, i ran it to my phpmyadmin:1 row inserted. 
Inserted row id: 267 ( Query took 0.0005 sec )

Comment: That is weird. Try to add `var_dump($sql->error);` after the prepare.

Comment: Ok, got it! db table not exist.